# Javascript How to keep DIV in window boundary

Tags: javascript, css

Hey I have a "box" div which can move its position based on clicking of arrows.  How can I keep the Box from going outside the window's bounds or in other words just go to the borders and not cross the boundaries.

Fiddle provided:

```
var elementStyle = document.getElementById("divId").style;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t9cqyqd/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle basically you need to add checks and if your check doesn't pass then set the new position to 0.

```
      if (newPosition < 0) {
          elementStyle.top = 0;
      } else {
          elementStyle.top = newPosition + px;      
      }
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8t9cqyqd/7/

for bottom and right the window will keep scrolling. If that's not desirable then you need to get the window size and do the same kind of check and then set the right and bottom positions to the container size minus the size of your moving box. I can update the fiddle for that if you'd like.

**updated fiddle to handle the "right" direction:**

https://jsfiddle.net/8t9cqyqd/9/

Comment: Hey you missed a couple of scenarios ...yeah if you can update that would be appreciated :0

Comment: For the bottom however you need to decide what the height is, I don't know what that would be though but you can work it out from the code for the moving to the right

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
var x = $("#divID").position();

if(x.left > $(window).width())
   //disable up arrow movement
```

Just do that for all positions changing out `width()` with `height()` for the Y position